# High coloum and line number while using the Raster Calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I downloaded the DEM25 from the [EU DEM homepage](http://land.copernicus.eu/pan-european/satellite-derived-products/eu-dem) and want to create in the end polygones for the exposition for an area of around 5000m² (like all mountainsites facing south are yellow etc.). So far, everything worked, except that in the Raster Calculator i get a huge number of coloums(aound 50000) and lines(45000) which are resulting in a big outputfile (over 10 Gig) after i used "actual layerdimension".
I tried to reduse the coloums (to 10000) and lines(9500). That worked, but i am not sure if i have overseen some big loss of data which i could regret later.
I had other DGM for a similiar region and in this i had just 2401 coloums and 2001 lines.
Has anybody an idea why the numbers are so high?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for the problem. The extend of my layer was still from the area E40N30 (Germany, Denmark etc.). I changed the extend by saving my small North Rhein-Westfalia Layer again and readjusted the extend. Now its working fine